# Perl can't load SSLeay.dll because LWP::Protocol::https is not installed

Tags: json, perl, cpan, finalbuilder, slack-api

For internal messaging the company I work for uses [Slack](https://slack.com/). It allows for a lot of awesome integration with tons of different software and services. I'm making my own bot for sending webhooks to Slack.

I got everything set up and working, I have a Perl script that sends a JSON payload. If I trigger the script manually, everything works flawlessly and my Slack bot sends messages.

However, when the script gets triggered by [Finalbuilder](https://www.finalbuilder.com/finalbuilder) (Software for automatic build processing), it it fails.
I get the following response:

```
501 Can't load 'C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.dll' for module Net::SSLeay: load_file:The specified module could not be found (LWP::Protocol::https not installed)
```

So I figured I needed to install the "LWP::Protocol::https" module. I just opened my cpan client and wrote `install LWP::Protocol::https`

Still get the error after installing the module.
I wrote `test LWP::Protocol:https`, which gave the following response:

```
Running test for module 'LWP::Protocol::https'
Running make for M/MS/MSCHILLI/LWP-Protocol-https-6.06.tar.gz
Checksum for C:\Strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\M\MS\MSCHILLI\LWP-Protocol-https-6.06.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\Strawberry\cpan\build for sizes
............................................................................DONE

  CPAN.pm: Going to build M/MS/MSCHILLI/LWP-Protocol-https-6.06.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for LWP::Protocol::https
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/https.pm blib\lib\LWP\Protocol\https.pm
  MSCHILLI/LWP-Protocol-https-6.06.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\c\bin\dmake.EXE -- OK
Running make test
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0,'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/apache.t ....... ok
t/https_proxy.t .. 1/56 # creating cert for direct.ssl.access
# creating cert for direct.ssl.access
# creating cert for foo
# creating cert for bar
# creating cert for foo
# creating cert for foo
# creating cert for bar
# creating cert for bar
t/https_proxy.t .. ok
All tests successful.
Files=2, Tests=61,  8 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr +  0.01 sys =  0.03 CPU)
Result: PASS
  MSCHILLI/LWP-Protocol-https-6.06.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\c\bin\dmake.EXE test -- OK
```

**I can trigger my script with windows CMD, or Finalbuilder. Both will work just fine**, but when the Finalbuilder project gets activated through Continua CI, I get the "can't load ssleay.dll" error.

**I have no clue what to do now. Does anyone know how I can fix the Perl error?**

Comment: Current versions of Strawberry Perl ship already with the necessary modules. Simply use a newer version.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the error message. LWP is reporting that LWP::Protocol::https isn't installed because it got an error when trying to load LWP::Protocol::https. That error being the one thrown by Net::SSLeay: Can't load 'C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.dll'. That means Net::SSLeay isn't properly installed.

Comment: Sorry if my question is poorly asked, I'm not familiar with Perl. I have Net-SSLeay-1.68 installed., and Net::SSLeay passes the cpan test.

Comment: You say that, yet when you you did `use Net::SSLeay;`, you got `Can't load 'C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.dll'`. That means you ran your code in a different environment than the one in which you ran your tests. (Include `@username` when talking to someone so they get notified.)

Comment: @ikegami I don't have `use Net::SSLeay` in the code. Here is my Perl script: https://gist.github.com/bearhagen/e969eaa23673e9484614

Comment: Not directly, but the code behind line 100 does.

Comment: @ikegami Oh okey. But it's in the same environment as the one I ran my tests. Continua CI (which starts the Finalbuilder project) is logged on as Adminstrator, which is the user I did my tests from. I installed Strawberry Perl earlier today.

Comment: You say they're the same, but then you spend the rest of your comment specifying differences.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error while running scripts from IDE, but not from command line (same issue).

My command line was adding these to the path. (These were not globally defined).

```
c:\perl\perl\bin;c:\perl\sup\bin;c:\perl\c\bin;
```

But the IDE didn't have these. So same fix should work for FinalBuilder, it is missing the perl path information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded the header files? I don't know what they are for Windows but in Linux, they're called: `libssl-dev` and `zlib1g-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error for awhile. In my case the solution was quite simple. It turned out that I hadn't restarted the SVN service, so when it ran the `post-commit.bat` file the PATH environment hadn't been updated to reflect the new paths that had been added during the Perl install.

While I was testing I was running from a new console window which had the correct PATH, but as soon as it ran from the batch file via SVN it broke, with exactly the same error you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with IDE Eclipse, command line fine but error with IDE.
I check the location:

```
C:\>perldoc -l LWP::Protocol::https
C:\zailperl\perl\vendor\lib\LWP\Protocol\https.pm
```

And I add it to Environments variables.
I didn't want to reboot my PC so I add the parent path to the IDE.
Right click on project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aufkb.png)